# TPH Query returning all objects despite OfType

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a very simple scenario.

Code-first, EF5, default model conventions

My Parent class has a collection of Children, which all derive from an abstract Child class.  Say I have ConcreteChild1 and ConcreteChild2.

If I try to retrieve ONLY ConcreteChild1, using `parent.Children.OfType<ConcreteChild1>()` the result will be a list of ConcreteChild1, as promised.  Unfortunately, examining the SQL that was issued reveals that ALL children were actualy retrieved from the DB, because the SQL issues "where Discriminator in (*each child type*)" NOT "where Discriminator in ('ConcreteChild1')" as I would expect.

What can I do to retrieve only the rows that match type?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14057561/edit) your questions to provide more information or to fix things.

Comment: Would it work if it were: parent.Children.Where(child => child is ConcreteChild1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation properties do not support queries as they are not `IQueryable` (they support LINQ to objects of course, but everything does that).

Construct an explicit query and execute it.

If you've used navigation properties like that in the past (ordering, filtering, ...) all of this did never run on the server. I think the cases where you want to access a sub-collection using a navigation property are *very* rare because of that limitation. It almost never makes sense.

Comment: That worked, thank you.  Even though it makes sense, it is very easy to invoke this trap when the apparent results are the same, and you do have reference to the collection after all, so why not use it?  It feels like sometimes EF gives me nice easy access to tools I can't use....